# With df.replace able to replace pd.NaT with any value but np.nan/None

Tags: python, pandas

With df.replace able to replace **pd.NaT** with any value but **np.nan/None**

**Note**: I have to do multiple data transformations where I'd be using fillna('') which wont work on NaT and I don't want chained replace as it's bit expensive on massive dataframes.

I have a df (provided after dtype info)

```
ID                                                  int64
TYPE                                                 object
NAME                                                object
LOCATION_ID                                        float64
COUNTRY_ID                                         float64
REGION_ID                                          float64
SLA_TIME_TO_FIRST_RESPONSE_START_TIME       datetime64[ns]
SLA_TIME_TO_FIRST_RESPONSE_STOP_TIME        datetime64[ns]
SLA_TIME_TO_RESOLUTION_START_TIME           datetime64[ns]
SLA_TIME_TO_RESOLUTION_STOP_TIME            datetime64[ns]
```

[image]

```
df.replace(pd.NaT,np.nan)
```

**Won't replace NaT to NaN**
[image]

```
df.replace(pd.NaT, 'anything')
```

**replaces NaT to 'anything'**
[image]

Comment: Can you add the output of `df.info()` of your original df (before replace) to the question?

Comment: @Ilya have included the df types and I want NaT to be replaced with NaNs as I have to do multiple data transformations where I'd be using fillna('') which wont work on NaT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` has some issues with types overall and that is why those `pd.NaT` and  'pd.NA' are for.
Here is an example of the issue when using the columns with `bool` type. After creating a `DataFrame` where one column `bool_type` holds only boolean values will be type 'bool' while another column `boot_with_none` containing booleans and 'None' values will be of type 'object'.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"bool_type": [True, False, True], "boot_with_none": [True, False, None]})
df.info()
#  #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
# ---  ------          --------------  ----- 
#  0   bool_type       3 non-null      bool  
#  1   boot_with_none  2 non-null      object
print(df)
#    bool_type boot_with_none
# 0       True           True
# 1      False          False
# 2       True           None
```

If we try to convert the `boot_with_none` column to type `bool`, it will automatically replace the 'None' value with 'False'.

```
df["boot_with_none"] = df["boot_with_none"].astype(bool)
df.info()
#  #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype
# ---  ------          --------------  -----
#  0   bool_type       3 non-null      bool 
#  1   boot_with_none  3 non-null      bool 
print(df)
#    bool_type  boot_with_none
# 0       True            True
# 1      False           False
# 2       True           False
```

One way to overcome this issue is to set the column type to `object` and then it can hold `None`s. In the following code you can see that one column is of type `datetime64` and another of type `object`. After the `replace` method, the column type `datetime64` remains with `pd.NaT`s while the `object` type column changes the value to `None`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'original_type': [np.datetime64("2018-01-01"), np.datetime64("2018-01-02"), None]})
df["object_type"] = df["original_type"].astype(object)
df.info()
#  #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
# ---  ------         --------------  -----         
#  0   original_type  2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
#  1   object_type    2 non-null      object  

df["original_type"] = df["original_type"].replace(pd.NaT, None)
df["object_type"] = df["object_type"].replace(pd.NaT, None)
print(df)
#   original_type          object_type
# 0    2018-01-01  2018-01-01 00:00:00
# 1    2018-01-02  2018-01-02 00:00:00
# 2           NaT                 None
```

**Edit**

Second issue is with `np.nan`. As `type(np.nan) == float`, it should be in a `float` type column (or 'object' type column). This example shows how pandas automatically converts a 'int' type column to 'float' type column and all its values to 'float's after setting one of the values to 'np.nan'. While 'object' type column remains with no change because it can hold arbitrary type of values.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"ints": [1, 2, 3]})
df["objects"] = df["ints"].astype(object)
df["ints_with_none"] = df["ints"]
df.loc[2, "ints_with_none"] = np.nan
df.info()
#  #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype
# ---  ------          --------------  -----
#  0   ints            3 non-null      int64
#  1   objects         3 non-null      object
#  2   ints_with_none  2 non-null      float64

print(df)
#    ints objects  ints_with_none
# 0     1       1             1.0
# 1     2       2             2.0
# 2     3       3             NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Fillna should work

```
df.fillna('anything')
```

If it doesnt work, check if they are truly pd.NaT objects. Using type.

```
type(df.iloc[1,0])
```

Comment: I have provided a note on my question. pls check, I want fillna('') which wont work on NaT

Comment: Try converting your datetime columns to str, and replacing. Nonetheles, if fillna method doesnt work, that mean they arent pd.NaT